# Data Connection Library app is missing in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, infopath, data-connection

I am trying to create a Data Connection library in SharePoint 2013 (for use with InfoPath) but the Data Connection Library app does not appear in the list of available apps.

I have already enabled the SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection features in the site collection.

Are there any other prerequisites that need to be installed or configured to make the app appear - I'm wondering if something like Office Web Apps server integrated with SharePoint 2013 might be required since this is not yet installed in the farm?

Comment: For new visitors, check all reason of [MISSING DATA CONNECTION LIBRARY IN SHAREPOINT](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/01/21/missing-data-connection-library-in-sharepoint/)

Answer (score 2):

OK, I fixed this. For some reason the DataConnectionLibrary feature was not activated in the site collection, I enabled the feature using Powershell as below:

Enable-SPFeature DataConnectionLibrary -url [SITE]

and the DataConnectionLibrary app appeared.